# Obtener un punto central entre varios GameObjects

Tags: unity3d, unity

He creado un juego en el que se pueden manejar X personajes a la vez de la misma forma y estos pueden morir en cualquier momento. Mi problema viene, cuando quiero que la cámara del juego englobe todos estos gameobjects.

**He pensado que una buena opción, es ir calculando el punto central entre los gameobjects que haya en la escena y hacer que la cámara siga ese punto a una cierta distancia.**

El código de la cámara ya lo tengo, pero me falta saber cómo obtengo ese punto central o si existe otra forma factible para hacer esto. Además, la cámara no sigue ninguno de los ejes (X,Y,Z) de forma lineal, ya que está colocada de tal forma para que se vea una vista isométrica (el juego es en 3D).

Como último dato importante, es que todos los gameobjects que están en ejecutándose en el juego (que estén vivos), están guardados en un `public static List<GameObject>` para poder acceder a los componentes de estos gameobjects en cualquier momento. Además, si muere o nace algún personaje (gameobject), se actualiza la lista sin problemas.

Os dejo un ejemplo gráfico con tres casos diferentes, siendo los puntos negros los personajes que hay en la escena (gameobjects) y los puntos rojos, el punto (vector) central que me gustaría conseguir.

[image]

Además, os dejo el código de la cámara para que podáis hacer pruebas si tenéis alguna solución:

```
public class Camera_Movement : MonoBehaviour {

    Vector3 newPos;
    public static List<GameObject> playersInGame = new List<GameObject>();

    void Update() {

        // Obtener vector central

        // Sustituir playersInGame[0].transform.position por el vector central
        //newPos = Vector3.Lerp(gameObject.transform.position, "vector central", Time.deltaTime);

        newPos = Vector3.Lerp(gameObject.transform.position, playersInGame[0].transform.position, Time.deltaTime);
        gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(newPos.x, newPos.y, newPos.z);

    }
}
```

¡Muchas gracias por adelantado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al final, la solución es más simple de lo que pensaba. Solo necesitaba aplicar las matemáticas básicas que, por cansancio, ni había pensado en ellas y que gracias a un [compañero de StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52375655/6129931), he conseguido hacer que funcione.

Aquí el resultado final:

```
public class Camera_Movement : MonoBehaviour {

    Vector3 newPos;
    float totalX, totalY, totalZ;

    void Update() {

        // Si todos los gameobjects manejables desaparecen, no volverá a entrar.
        if (Game_Controller.playersInGame.Count != 0) {

            // Obtener vector central = Sumar todos los valores de cada eje para después
            // dividirlos por el número total de gameobjects
            // Nota: La "List<GameObject> playersInGame" esta alojada en el script "Game_Controller"
            for (int i = 0; i < Game_Controller.playersInGame.Count; i++) {
                totalX += Game_Controller.playersInGame[i].transform.position.x;
                totalY += Game_Controller.playersInGame[i].transform.position.y;
                totalZ += Game_Controller.playersInGame[i].transform.position.z;
            }
            Vector3 center = new Vector3(totalX / Game_Controller.playersInGame.Count, totalY / Game_Controller.playersInGame.Count, totalZ / Game_Controller.playersInGame.Count);

            // Se hace una interpolación entre la posición de la cámara y el centro de forma progresiva
            newPos = Vector3.Lerp(gameObject.transform.position, center, Time.deltaTime);
            // Se le da la nueva posición a la cámara
            gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(newPos.x, newPos.y, newPos.z);

            // Se restablece los datos a 0 para volver a obtener otro centro actualizado
            totalX = 0;
            totalY = 0;
            totalZ = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Esta cámara no hace *zoom-in/zoom-out*, si da la casualidad de que un gameobject está fuera de la vista de la cámara, pero sería una buena actualización del código de arriba. Si alguien quiere incluirlo y lo consigue, que edite esta respuesta y lo comparta con toda la comunidad.

¡Muchas gracias a todos!

*NOTA: El [post original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52375649/get-the-center-point-between-many-gameobjects-in-unity) está publicado en StackOverflow en inglés. Lo he publicado aquí porque me parece interesante ampliar la comunidad en español con preguntas que no se han resuelto o preguntado.*